# Can't get HTTP PUT request to work in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, angular, rest, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-routing

I'm trying to update an entry in the `game` table. However, my PUT request in ASP.NET never seems to trigger, and I can't figure out why.

This is controller in ASP.NET:

```
[Route("game/{update.GameID}")]
[HttpPut]
public IActionResult updateGame([FromBody]Game update)
{
    var result = context.Games.SingleOrDefault(g => g.GameID == update.GameID);
    if (result != null)
    {
        result = update;
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
    return Created("", result);
}
```

And this is the code I use in Angular:

```
url:string;
constructor(private _http: HttpClient) {
    this.url = "https://localhost:44359/api/v1/"
};

putGame(id:number, game:Game){
    return this._http.put(this.url + "game/" + id, game);
}
```

Edit 1: I do have a list of GET-requests, which all work just fine. It's only the PUT-request that fails.

Comment: Do your other ASP.Net controllers successfully invoke Angular?  Q: Have you tried using RouteDebugger?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are using `PUT` request you need to add a resource id either to update or create new - so just don't combine your id with your object

```
[HttpPut("game/{id}")]
public IActionResult UpdateGame(int id, [FromBody]Game update) {
    //...
}
```

If you are using **Asp.net Core** you can just re-write your URL on your HTTP verbs attribute like the code above - So pass your resource id in the URL and bind your object in the body - Your URL should read as `https://localhost:44359/api/v1/game/2`

Hope this helps you - Happy coding !!

Answer (score 2):

The route template parameter `{update.GameID}` is not standard to what is suggested by documentation

Assuming the game id is an integer review the following

```
//PUT .../game/5
[Route("game/{id:int}")]
[HttpPut]
public IActionResult updateGame(int id, [FromBody]Game update) {
    //...
}
```

Reference [Routing to controller actions in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing)

I would also suggest you review the logic of the action as I do not believe it is doing what you think it does with updating the entity returned from the context.

Comment: Yup. `result = update` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: I did this, but it still won't call when I try out the put-request. I have added a breakpoint on `updateGame()` and attempt a put-request via postman, but it never triggers.

Comment: As @Nkosi suggests, it may not do what you expect it should. Also check out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-2.1, there is an PUT example.

Answer (score 1):

Can you modify your defining route just like

```
[Route("game")]
[HttpPut]
public IActionResult updateGame([FromBody]Game update)
{
   //your code
}
```

And call from angular like

```
putGame(game:Game){
    return this._http.put(this.url + "game", game);
}
```

you can receive gameid from game object so don't need from url