# Can't get HTTP PUT request with one parameter, is it possible?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-web-api, sql-update, grpc

I'm trying doing an update using the User Id via gRPC

I have a Web Api who is consuming gRPC data

The question is almost similar to this one:
[Can't get HTTP PUT request to work in ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53244551/cant-get-http-put-request-to-work-in-asp-net-core)

But I need to pass Just the Id and that is obtained through the user.UserId because we can't  have 2 messages like this

```cs
[HttpPut("{id_2}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<Empty>> UpdateUser([FromRoute] string id_2,[FromRoute] ShowUserId user){

  //wrong (it's impossible unless you who are reading this and understands gRPC know a way 
  //to do this)
}
```

So I Try this but it don't work in the backend (don't do nothing wrong or updates is useless)

WebApi Controller

```cs
[HttpPut("{user.UserID}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<Empty>> UpdateUser([FromRoute] ShowUserId user)
{
    //here gets the id of the user when it does the login
    user.UserID = Request.Cookies["LoginUserId_2"];

    var user5 = _context.Users_5.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id.ToString().Equals(user.UserID));

    if(user5 == null)
    {
        return Unauthorized("User don't exist idk why");
    }

    user.Username = user5!.Username;
    user.Email = user5!.Email;
    user.Age = user5!.Age;
    user.Test = user5!.Test;
            
    var results = await _userClient.UpdateAsync(user);
            
    return Ok(results);
}
```

gRPC Proto and Service

Proto

```
service UserAuth {
  rpc Update (ShowUserId) returns (Empty);
  //...
}

message ShowUserId {
  string userID = 1;
  string username = 2;
  string email = 3;
  int32 age = 4;
  bool test = 5;
}

message Empty {

}

//messages...
```

gRPC Service (C#)

```cs
public override async Task<Empty> Update(ShowUserId request, ServerCallContext context)
{
    var guid = Guid.Parse(request.UserID.ToString());

    var data = _context.Users_5.Where(x => x.Id.Equals(guid)).FirstOrDefault();
    if(data == null)
    {
        throw new Exception("Invalid User, User don't exist and can't be updated");
    }

    data.Username = request.Username;
    data.Email = request.Email;
    data.Age = request.Age;
    data.Test = request.Test;
    _context.Users_5.Update(data);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return await Task.FromResult(new Empty());
```

I also have the frontEnd and it updates!! Except in the database, who should update :c

So the problem should be in the backend as I described earlier

It is possible using just one parameter (and if yes how to do that)? If is possible with two, how to do that (attention i'm using gRPC Services, not like `long id` or `string id` in the parameters)

Any help/answer is always welcome

Comment: Ok, that's right, I already edited my post but just to give you an idea: my content may even be the same but the question was different, it didn't ask how to do an update and in this one it only asks how to get the {id} of a right put and of why it is not working either right or wrong, by the way I have an identical post but it is with delete and I can already tell you that the mistakes I make are not the same. If you see the ways the create the httpPUT and httpDelete for example, the methods are quite different and more complex with frontend mixes with gRPC so the question is different itself

Comment: About the [FromRoute] comment, The route I need to use just something like {user.UserID} and the correct answer of the previous question just doesn't match there's an idea I want so I put an example of how I couldn't do it/I wanted to avoid doing it